# How can I set the scale of 2 axis same as each other?

Tags: matlab, axis

I read a wave file by this code :

```
[filename pathname]=uigetfile('*.wav', 'Select a wave file');
[y,fs,nbits]=wavread(fullfile(pathname, filename));
```

and plot it's spectrogram and wave form by this codes:

```
axes(handles.axes1);
plot(y);

axes(handles.axes2);
spectrogram(y,str2double(get(handles.Frame,'String')), str2double(get(handles.Overlap,'String')),[], str2double(get(handles.Samplef ,'String'))*1000, 'yaxis');
```

But I have many differences in axis scales! I want both plots have same X-axis scale(in seconds or milliseconds), How can I do that?
I did xlim but didn't get appropriate result :(

Comment: Can you post some code that can work by itslef please? If you do xlim to both plots axes you will get what you want. What does it mean they where "not appopiate"?

Comment: My x_axis data was wrong and when I did xlims of two plots equal, one of them  was giving wrong plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `plot(y)` the X-Axis does not represent **time** but only the **index** of each data point.

You have to build a proper time vector and use it as XData for your plot.
something like

```
[y,fs,nbits]=wavread(fullfile(pathname, filename));
xtime = (0:numel(y)-1)/fs ; %// build a time vector according to sampling frequency
```

and then later :

```
axes(handles.axes1);
plot( xtime , y ); %// plot 'y' versus TIME
```

now the time vectors on both plots should be similar and XLim should work ok. *(provided you send the right sampling frequency to the spectrogram. You seem to read it from a textbox and multiply it by 1000. Make sure the spectrogram command receive the same sampling frequency as was returned by `wavread`.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it but opposite!( plot(y, totaltime).